# Como paso el valor de un input::file por ajax de la vista a un controlador

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

Tengo un script el cual me envia la informacion del formulario al controlador, pero al usar el valor del input file obtengo que el valor de ese campo es null

"message": "Call to a member function store() on **null**"

```js
<script>
    function saveAbsence() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '{{url('/emp/newAbsence')}}',
            data: {
                absenceDate: $('#absenceDate').val(),
                note: $('#note').val(),
                absenceDateEnd: $('#absenceDateEnd').val(),
                absenceFile: $('#absenceFile').val()
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log( $('#absenceFile'))
                // location.reload();
            },
            error: function (data) {
                showAjaxErrors(data, 'error_msg');
                markError(['absenceDate', 'absenceDateEnd', 'note']);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

```html
{{ Form::open(array('url' => '/saveAbsence'), ['id' => 'absenceForm'], ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'], ['files'=> true]) }}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            {{Form::file('image')}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
    {{ Form::button('Guardar', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'onClick' => 'saveAbsence()']) }}
</div>
```

Comment: lo que el error dice es que la `funcion store` no existe. deberias de mostrar la parte del servidos, ya que el error no tiene nada que ver con el codigo que muestras

Comment: La funcion store si existe y esta instanciada, solo que necesita un VALOR y el problema radica en que ese VALOR lo estoy enviando al controlador desde el formulario por medio de ajax, pero el valor no esta llegando por eso muestra NULL

Comment: Al hacer dd($request->file('image')) me muestra NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUCIONADO, de la siguiente manera: utilizando **FormData**

```
<script>
function saveAbsence() {
        var datos = new FormData();
        datos.append('absenceDate', $('#absenceDate').val());
        datos.append('absenceDateEnd', $('#absenceDateEnd').val());
        datos.append('note', $('#note').val());
        datos.append('absenceFile', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '{{url('/emp/newAbsence')}}',
            data: datos,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (data) {
                location.reload();
            },
            error: function (data) {
                showAjaxErrors(data, 'error_msg');
                markError(['absenceDate', 'absenceDateEnd', 'note', 'absenceFile']);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Primero que todo, te recomiendo leer [este ejemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48231432/simple-ajax-in-laravel) . Lo importante es que debes pasar el token de certificación para evitar ataques de XSS.

Por lo que debes agregar a la data de tu ajax lo siguiente.

```
data: { _token: '{{ csrf_token() }}' }
```

Comment: Bueno el evento onClick lo estoy manejando directamente en el button de enviar el formulario, y ademas del token el ejemplo no es de gran ayuda a la pregunta.